# $_FILES['file']['name'][0] не возвращает первый файл

Tags: php, ajax

$_FILES['file']['name'][0] возвращает первую букву имени файла. В интернете перечитал кучу мануалов.

> Предположим, что были загружены файлы /home/test/some.html и
>   /home/test/file.bin. В таком случае переменная
>   $_FILES['userfile']['name'][0] будет иметь значение some.html, а
>   переменная $_FILES['userfile']['name'][1] - значение file.bin.
>   Аналогично, переменная $_FILES['userfile']['size'][0] будет содержать
>   размер файла some.html и так далее.

Использую denwer, изображения передаю через ajax:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('file', files[i]);
}
```

Один файл отлично загружается и сохраняется, но не могу организовать отправку 2ух и более файлов.

Как на PHP получить список загруженный файлов, что бы в цикле их сохранить?

UPD: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES['userfile']); echo '</pre>';`

выводит: `<pre></pre>`

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES['file']); echo '</pre>';
```

выводит:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [name] => CauSYrOVs7k.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => Z:\tmp\php6923.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 146070
)
</pre>
```

Вероятнее всего ошибка здесь:

```
<script>
    $("#btnAddAd").click(function () {
        var files = $('#input-ficons-1').fileinput('getFileStack');
        var description = $('#description').val();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('description', description);

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('file', files[i]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            url: 'ajax/uploaded-image.php',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

"var files" содержит "[object File],[object File]", т.е. передается 2 изображения.

Comment: а вы покажите что выводит `print_r` при нескольких файлах)

Answer (score 3):

`$_FILES['file']['name'][0]` - выводит первую букву

`$_FILES[0]['name']` - выводит имя первого файла

Comment: Всю интригу испортили((

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте файлы правильно:

```
<form id = "filesForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" multiply name="files[]" />
</form>
<script>
 ...
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(document.getElementById('filesForm')),
        url: 'ajax/uploaded-image.php',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Обратите внимание на поле **data** и параметры поля для выбора файла. На сервере вы должны увидеть в print_r($_FILES) все загружаемые файлы.