# Ajax загрузка нескольких изображений

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, массивы

Не могу сообразить как загрузить 2 и более изображений на сервер.

```
<script>
    $("#btnAddAd").click(function () {
        var files = $('#input-ficons-1').fileinput('getFileStack');
        var description = $('#description').val();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('description', description);

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('file', files);
        }

        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           url: 'ajax/uploaded-image.php',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           multiple: true,
           success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
           }
        });
    })
</script>
```

PHP: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES['file']); echo '</pre>';`

Выводит:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [name] => CauSYrOVs7k.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => Z:\tmp\php6923.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 146070
)
</pre>
```

Не могу понять как пройтись по массиву изображений на PHP, с JS Ajax вроде как передает все файлы.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что явный дубликат своего же вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528555/filesfilename0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   formData.append('files[]', files[i]);
}
```

PHP:

```
echo $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
echo "\n<br>\n";
echo $_FILES['files']['name'][1];
```